# How to avoid deadlock of application due to loop over large set of data?

Tags: c++, qt

The following  function will take points(latitude - longitude) from vector of points **collectLatlong** and check if distance between point1 to point 2 is in range of 100m to 140m if it is then point2 will be stored in a separate vector of points **filteredpoints**.

Then from point2 distance between next point in the **collectLatlong** vector is calculated, in this way all points in **collectLatlong** are iterated .

The function consists of

1) collection of latitude and longitute of points in a vector - collectLatlong

2) calculateDistance function is used to find distance between two points(lat-lon)

3)  It uses QGIS API . QgsPoint means a point(lat-long point) similar two QPoint in QT.

4) I am using QT in ubuntu.

Problem:

This function will be called at runtime after collecting points in **collectLatlong** after calling this function the application will perform good if the number of points are in **collectLatlong** are less but if it is more application is not responding to any other operation ultimately i need to kill the app to close it.

feel free to ask queries regarding my question.

Help me to solve this issue. Thank you.

```
void filterPoints()
 {
 int size=collectLatlong.size()-1;
 float Dis;
 int A2= 0, B2 = 5;
 Loop:
 if(B2<=size)
 {
 QgsPoint a = collectLatlong[A2] ;  QgsPoint b = collectLatlong[B2];

 Dis = calculateDistance(a,b);


 if(Dis >= 100 && Dis <= 140)
           {

            filteredpoint.push_back(b);

            A2=B2; B2=B2+5;

            goto Loop;

        }

 else if (Dis<100)
        {
            B2++;
            goto Loop;
        }
 else
 {
     B2--;
     goto Loop;
 }

}
} 

float calculateDistance(const QgsPoint& a, const QgsPoint& b)
{
        double pi = 3.14/180.0;
        double Ab,c,d , dLat,dLon,lat1,lat2,lon1,lon2;
        int R= 6371;
        lat1=a.y()*pi; lat2=b.y()*pi;
        lon1=a.x()*pi; lon2=b.x()*pi;

        dLat = lat2-lat1;
        dLon = lon2-lon1;

        Ab = sin(dLat/2)*sin(dLat/2)+sin(dLon/2)*sin(dLon/2)*cos(lat1)*cos(lat2);
        c = 2*atan2(sqrt(Ab),sqrt(1-Ab));
        d=R*c*1000;
        return d;


  }
```

Comment: You do realize you would use a `while` loop rather that `goto`, don't you?

Comment: ... QT is QuickTime. Qt is what you mean.

Answer (score 4):

first you can remove the `goto`s and replace the first `if` with a `while`

there are 2 options to fix this

1. first you will need to split up the work and use a timer to repeatedly run a chunk of work
2. you can run the loop in a background thread and report the partial results with signals back to the gui thread

Answer (score 0):

Addon to @ratchet freak answer:

3/ You can call QApplication::processEvents() somewhere inside your loop. But you should understand Qt event loops logic. Such usecases may cause performance issues.

IMO, using QThreads or QtConcurrent is more prefferable.